# jquery ajaxchimp in wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, mailchimp

I am trying to utilize ur plugin in wordpress.
Everything is working fine except the ajax messages for success/error etc.
Can u please help? I am new with jQuery/Ajax.
I am using the code in ur download file with change in form action. 
Thank you in advance.

```
    <div id="email">
        <span>Enter your email to sign up</span>
        <form action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/subscribe.php" id="invite" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" name="email" id="address" data-validate="validate(required, email)"/>
            <button type="submit">&#187;</button>
        </form>
        <span id="result"></span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#invite').ketchup().submit(function() {
            if ($(this).ketchup('isValid')) {
                var action = $(this).attr('action');
                $.ajax({
                    url: action,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        email: $('#address').attr('value')
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#result').html(data).css('color', 'green');
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $('#result').html('Sorry, an error occurred.').css('color', 'red');
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your email  field (#address) doesn't have a value attribute, try `email: $('#address').val()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply Anand. I made the change and its still not working. The success or error messages are displayed in subscribe.php instead of the same page.BTW I got the above code from: https://gist.github.com/mfkp/1488819

Comment: Is there a page where this can be seen in action?

Comment: Have checked the HTML output of your page and it doesn't contain `<span id="result"></span>` element, add it to your page and the output from subscribe.php will get displayed.

Comment: Thanks... Yes. made the result show within the text box. Thanks a bunch Anand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between properties and attributes, you are assigning the `value` attribute which doesn't exist in the markup of your email input field, so you need to access the value using the `val()` property

Change

```
email: $('#address').attr('value')
```

to

```
email: $('#address').val();
```